# How to compare two csv files and find difference using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two csv files , I want to compare both files and find difference.It contains user_id

I tried with compare-object, diff but could not achieve.

like

AD_Users.csv

Oracle_Users.csv

both contains user id , output should be like

AD user does not exist in Oracle

Oracle user does not exist in AD

eg -  K9988484
      J8485888

I tried with compare-object, diff but could not achieve.

Comment: Can you post examples of your CSV files including headers and some data please?

Comment: Also the commands you tried using with Compare-Object...

Comment: Why must you use Powershell? Why is a dedicated file comparer like Beyond Compare not acceptable?

Comment: Hi Andy, It contains user_id like in one column like Y984848 B984848

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your csv files look like this:

```
# contents of ad.csv
user_id,field1,field2
useronlyad,value1,value2
userboth,value3,value4
```

and this:

```
# contents of oracle.csv
user_id,field1,field2
useronlyoracle,value1,value2
userboth,value3,value4
```

You could get the ad users that are not oracle users like this (borrowing New-HashSet from [Josh Einstein](http://cid-89e05724af67a39e.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/PowerShell/Modules/Scripting)):

```
# to return all ad users that are not oracle users
import-module .\Scripting.psm1
$ad_hashset = new-hashset string
$oracle_hashset = new-hashset string
import-csv .\ad.csv | ForEach-Object {$ad_hashset.add($_.user_id)}
import-csv .\oracle.csv | ForEach-Object {$oracle_hashset.add($_.user_id)}
$ad_hashset.ExceptWith($oracle_hashset)
$ad_hashset # will return useronlyad
```

Similarly, you could get the oracle users that are not ad users like this

```
# to return all ad users that are not oracle users
import-module .\Scripting.psm1
$ad_hashset = new-hashset string
$oracle_hashset = new-hashset string
import-csv .\ad.csv | ForEach-Object {$ad_hashset.add($_.user_id)}
import-csv .\oracle.csv | ForEach-Object {$oracle_hashset.add($_.user_id)}
$oracle_hashset.ExceptWith($ad_hashset)
$oracle_hashset # will return useronlyoracle
```

**Brief explanation** of how this works:

1. Create two collections (hashsets)
2. Populate the hashsets with the data found in their corresponding CSV
3. Removes all elements in the second collection from the first collection

Comment: Hi Jon, I dont know why it's downvote, I tried the above script but the problem is that I am not getting any output in both files.

Comment: @Naveenk I've modified the examples to work on csv files with a fieldname user_id (as you described in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Diff will diff CSV files in an easier to read format for the output, but it does not work on CLI.  Be sure to change the default language setting to CSV or it will not output as you would expect.  This tool allows any other character to be the separating character instead of forcibly imposing the use of the comma.

http://prettydiff.com/

Comment: I dont want to use any tool , Only powershell because I have to modiy some existing scripts