# Compare two csv files and find discrepancies

Tags: powershell

I am new in powershell world , I got some project on powershell for inventory reconciling .

I am not sure how to proceed on this , I tried some basic steps and I am able to export

users/group/group membership.

Following are the requirements :

- Now What I have achieved - Thanks to Govnah

AD query:

```
Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 |
Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName, @{Name="Groups";Expression={(Get-QADMemberOf $_ | Select-Object -expandProperty Name) -join ";"}} | 
Sort-Object SamAccountName | 
export-csv $FilePath
```

I have now two csv files likes `AD_users.csv` and `Oracle_users.csv`

I want to compare both files and redirect the difference like

AD users does not exist in Oracle
Oracle User does not exist in AD

Sample data

AD_users.csv

```
u388848993
K847447388
u994888484
```

Oracle_users.csv

```
k095848889
u388848993
```

I can query oracle database , AD query is also fine the only concern is that I am not able to compare the output.

Comment: Let's see your CSV file data. Update your question with examples of both. Replace sensitive information with example text.

Comment: Are these the only columns in csv file? Shouldn't there also be column name at the top?

Comment: As @user978511 points out, looks like you are missing headers `dn, sAMAcountName, Groups` and associated data example text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two csv files and find difference using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791586/how-to-compare-two-csv-files-and-find-difference-using-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it something like this in a script I wrote:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$adlist = Get-Content c:\users\sverker\desktop\ad.csv |Sort-Object
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$oraclelist = Get-Content c:\users\sverker\desktop\oracle.csv |Sort-Object
$Matching_numbers = @()

ForEach ($number in $adlist)
{
  if ($oraclelist.Contains($number))
  {
        $Matching_numbers += $number
  }
}
ForEach ($number in $Matching_numbers)
{
  $adlist.Remove($number)
  $oraclelist.Remove($number)
}
```

now $Matching_numbers now contains the matching numbers
and $adlist contains only numbers from AD
and $oraclelist only numbers from Oracle

you can then loop through the list and display values:

```
Write-Host "Matches:"
ForEach ($value in $Matching_numbers)
{
  $Message += $value + [Environment]::NewLine
}
Write-Host $Message

Write-Host "AD only:"
ForEach ($value in $adlist)
{
  $MessageAd += $value + [Environment]::NewLine
}
Write-Host $MessageAd

Write-Host "Oracle only:"
ForEach ($value in $oraclelist)
{
  $MessageOracle += $value + [Environment]::NewLine
}
Write-Host $MessageOracle
```

or simply by writing

```
$Matching_numbers
```

will output the list to console

You can output the $Message variables to a file or so..

No doubt, there is a nicer way to do it, but this worked for me for a certain type of file.

Comment: Yeah, why didn't I think of that. Guess I still haven't understood that Powershell has the power of .Net :) I'll update the answer

Comment: obvious now that you mention it :)

Comment: then you should write only $oraclelist and $adlist to an output with perhaps using `$oraclelist | Out-File C:\oracleonly.txt`

Comment: Nope, It took lots of time and still redirected to Match User id , user id which contains in both file. No difference

Comment: Hi , Could you please help to find differences , I am getting only matched record

Comment: Can you post all the code? Perhaps on pastebin.com but remove/rename any sensitive parts.

Comment: I have pasted the code on pastebin. Please have a look thanks.

Comment: The code you pasted works as expected. Perhaps something is missing in the system? .NET-version or Powershell version? In your sample, there are three numbers out of four that appears in the oracleonly.txt file, which is correct, since there is only one number matching in the sample data you gave.

Comment: I tried with different input files , It seems it's working fine when input files have less record. However in my actual file there are more than 13000 records and I am not getting valid output.After execution both output file contains similar records not difference. May be I am asking too much question. Sorry for that.Thanks.

Comment: I found, What was wrong [System.Collections.ArrayList]$adlist = Get-Content c:\Output\AD.csv  | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' ' } , it's working fine now as excepted. Thanks a lot. BIG THANKS for nice script.